# Mistake in this definition from Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book and on page 64 the author has enunciated the following definition:

[image]

However, on page 81 the author has stated that:

[image]

I think Conway was mistaken in the first definition. If I remember well from my algebraic topology classes, the second definition is the true definition of $\gamma^{-1}$.

Comment: "This is actually a reparametrization of the original definition”.

Comment: As egreg points out, he notes the change himself. Also, the original isn't given as a formal definition, just a notation for the theorem that follows it, which is about properties of the integral, not homotopy.